# format ISO date/time and later compare to phone's date/time

Tags: android

I've got a String of a date/time in ISO-8601 format, like: `2011-04-15T20:08:18Z`

I want to format this to a more readable date/time and then also be able to compare that later to the phone's local time. I'm a bit confused about what's been deprecated and what hasn't. 
Do I need to use a `Calendar` object?

Can someone walk me through how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

following is a code snippet you can use

```
StringBuffer sbDate = new StringBuffer();
sbDate.append(cDate);
String newDate = sbDate.substring(0, 19).toString();
String rDate = newDate.replace("T", " ");
String nDate = rDate.replaceAll("-", "/");
```

**nDate** will give you date in normal format, to compare two dates continue like

```
long epoch = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").parse(nDate).getTime();
Date currentDate = new Date();
long diffInSeconds = (currentDate.getTime() - epoch) / 1000;
String elapsed = "";
long seconds = diffInSeconds;
long mins = diffInSeconds / 60;
long hours = diffInSeconds / 3600;
long days = diffInSeconds / 86400;
long weeks = diffInSeconds / 604800;
long months = diffInSeconds / 2592000;

if (seconds < 120) {
    elapsed = "a min ago";
} else if (mins < 60) {
    elapsed = mins + " mins ago";
} else if (hours < 24) {
    elapsed = hours + " "+ (hours > 1 ? "hrs" : "hr")+ " ago";
} else if (hours < 48) {
    elapsed = "a day ago";
} else if (days < 7) {
    elapsed = days + " days ago";
} else if (weeks < 5) {
    elapsed = weeks + " " + (weeks > 1 ? "weeks" : "week") + " ago";
} else if (months < 12) {
    elapsed = months" " + (months > 1 ? "months" : "months")+ " ago";
} else {
    elapsed = "more than a year ago";
}
```

This way you'll be able to get date in proper format as well as you'll be able to compare the dates and get the difference in Years, months, weeks, days, hours, mins or secs.